# Question on If-Else statements on XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, xcode4

Is using this code:

```
if (foobar == 1)    
{  
 method(a)  
}   
else if (foobar == 2)      
{   
 method(b)   
}

void method (foo)   
{   
//method 1foo   
//method 2foo   
//method 3foo   
}
```

makes it more faster, or compile to a smaller executable, than this code:

```
if (foobar == 1)    
{   
//method 1a   
//method 2a   
//method 3a   
}   
else if (foobar == 2)   
{   
//method 1b   
//method 2b   
//method 3b   
}
```

or has any effect at all when compiled on Xcode?

I know the codes are sketchy. Sorry.
Thanks for the tip on the edit, Mr. Dave.

Comment: should there be assignments in the second code sample?

Comment: Define "better".  Do you mean "faster", or "more readable", or maybe "will compile to a smaller executable"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Don't Repeat Yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). Yes, you can avoid the tiny overhead of a function call by eliminating the function and copying its contents everywhere you use it, but that's not a good way to speed up your program. The difference in speed will be so small that you probably won't be able to detect it even after many, many iterations. And you're just begging for bugs where you change one spot but not the other(s).

Comment: For readability purposes though, which is better.
Also, thanks for the DRY link.

Comment: For readability purposes, the first is far, far better. Every time you repeat code, there's a possibility that the code isn't really the same. If you call the same function from several places, the reader knows right away that the code is the same in each place. There are limits, of course, so use your judgement. Don't create a separate function just because a pair of lines occurs two or three times in your app. You normally wouldn't use a function just to call +alloc and then -init, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the main difference you're asking about is in the use of the external method outside your conditional statement...

No, not that I can think of. However, in any language it's usually a good idea to encapsulate common functionality in a single method wherever possible, to keep things organized and easy to read. In other words, I'd go with your first option. =)

Answer (score 1):

What you've described is known as [inlining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion). Inlining generally makes the code faster, but it can make the code slower in certain cases. In any case, unless the rest of the code is already highly optimised and it's in a very tight loop, you won't notice any speed difference.

Comment: Thanks for the link.
In any case, which would you recommend for readability of code?